# How can I know that my child process is actually reaped after a call to waitpid()?

Tags: c, process, posix

**Question**

In an effort to have my program look after itself, I fork a child process and later monitor it with:

```
pid_t w = waitpid(cpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
```

This blocks my parent process until the child A) exited, B) receives a signal or C) is stopped. At this point I would like the parent to decide on behalf of the child whether it should be allowed to "live on" or not.

**A**) In the cases where the child has already exited, the waitpid() call is supposed to reap it as a dead child, but in my experience this is not the case. Even if I wait for the child when it exits, it still shows up in the process list after the parent has exited. How can I know if a child has been reaped or not after my waitpid() call? What would be the correct way to kill it off if it turns out to still be alive?

**B**) In the cases where the child received a signal such as SIGSEGV and the parent decides to terminate the child, how can this be done? Is SIGKILL the only option? By sending SIGTERM will I simply invoke another (recursive) waitpid()?

**C**) When a trap occurs or the child for some other reason has its execution stopped, how would I go about killing it then? Is SIGKILL still the only option?

**Answer**

Answers with simple source code are preferred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. You need to use the `W...` macros from `sys/wait.h` on `status` to determine if the process exited. If it did, **it has been reaped**. There is nothing else for you to do, and in fact any future use of the pid to try to "check if it was reaped" would be invalid since the pid has been freed and could be re-assigned to a different (new) process.

B. What happens when the child receives a signal like `SIGSEGV` has nothing to do with the parent. Unless the signal is caught, the process terminates.

C. If `waitpid` returns with a `status` of "stopped" and you want to kill it, you can either send a catchable signal that would kill it (like `SIGTERM`) followed by `SIGCONT`, or you can use `SIGKILL`.

Comment: I am using the W... macros that you mention already. There must be a bug in my program since the child processes are clearly not reaped. I am marking this as the correct answer. Thanks!